# replace not working after specific number

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column `vouchn`. The recod of this column eg-if it receipt voucher it will record like RV103 AND LIKE payment it stores like PV99. I also use this sql for gettin max records.

```
SELECT MAX(REPLACE(vouchn, 'RV', '')) AS vcno 
FROM dbo.dayb 
WHERE (vouchn LIKE '%RV%')
```

it is ok until i reach RV999. After then even record RV1000 is there the above sql retrieve RV999. What is the error of the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `REPLACE(vouchn, 'RV', '')` always return `numeric` result, you can as the below:

```
SELECT MAX(REPLACE(vouchn, 'RV', '') * 1) AS vcno 
FROM dbo.dayb 
WHERE (vouchn LIKE '%RV%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to numeric type:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(BIGINT,REPLACE(vouchn, 'RV', ''))) AS vcno 
FROM dbo.dayb 
WHERE (vouchn LIKE '%RV%')
```